# How to lock out login attempts with SQL

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql, security, captcha

I don't want by server to get brute forced but I don't want to use a CAPTCHA as they're not user friendly / I don't want to rely on another company - because I'm not going to implement my own captcha system.

I've thought of creating a `attempts` table with this structure:

```
________________________________________________________________
|         IP         |      ATTEMPTS      |        LOCK        |
|‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾|
|       1.1.1.1      |         0          |          2         |
|        ....        |        ....        |        ....        |
‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾          Yes I had fun making this
```

And let the user have 5-10 attempts, before resetting to 0 and 
increasing the lock time by a factor of 2 - it's in minutes.

Is this a good method to lock out a brute force?

I'd have logic like this on my server: - abstracted

```
....
* on request to server do below  *

db.query("SELECT * FROM attempts WHERE IP= *REQUEST.IP* ",function(result){
    if (result.rows.length > 0 && result.rows[0].attempts > 5) {
        if (CheckIfExpired(results.rows[0].lock)) {
            if (loginFail) MultplyLockBy2();
            else RemoveFromAttemptsTable();
        } else res.status("403").send("You're locked out");
    } else normalLoginAttempt().ifFal(add1toAttempts());
....
```

I have a feeling there's a more efficient way to do this natively in SQL, I'm a novice with SQL.
(I'm using postgresql).

After looking at this I'm guessing I'd need a start-time field aswell, so I can calculate when the lock has expired.

ASP.net + Njinx/Apache + sessions + ... != node.js + sql

Comment: @NeilMcGuigan This is definitely not the duplicate of a ASP.Net question

Comment: The accepted answer (yours) is actually quite bad in my opinion as it involves writing state for unauthenticated calls (ie. an attacker can fill up your disk using distinct user names each call).  I would *consider* your answer *on Windows paltforms*, where something like `fail2ban` is not readily available. For a nodejs app, running in a presumably Linux environment, there are already better solution ready, tested, widely used.

Comment: I'm really confused. I think I may implement fail2ban; I'll implement that cookie that always allows a user to connect back into their account without captcha; and I'll also maybe use a captcha in conjunction with a lockout; is this a good solution?

Comment: What have you implemented in your production app to stop this kind of a behaviour ??

Answer (score 0):

Use [`fail2ban`](http://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page). You HTTP request should return 401 (unauthorized) and your fail2ban filter should match the access_log for consecutive 401 and ban the caller for 10 minutes or so (at IP firewall level).

As you notice, the answer has nothing to do with SQL, postgresql, nor nodejs.

Comment: Will it be controled by the server, or handled externally by the fail2ban program?

Comment: Who si the `server` in your question?

Comment: as in my node app; I've read the page and it seem's I'd update a log file and fail2ban will handle it all automatically?

Comment: you don't update any log file. Your nginx or your apache server already have a log, I did not used the name `access_log` for no reason. `fail2ban` is a serivce that will handle this automatically, if configured so. This is not something your app does. Is all triggered by the correct HTTP status return and by the correct filter rule.

Comment: I'm using Node solely, does it implicitely use Apache/nginx behind the scenes?

Comment: this is trivially defeated using an anonymizing proxy

Comment: Is highly unusual  directly node serve in production. It usually sits behind a proper HTTP server (nginx or apache), eg. areverse proxy or a passenger nodejs app

Comment: Isit better to do so? It's working at the moment however I want a sustainable robust and secure app

Comment: @NeilMcGuigan bots and crawlers don't bother masquerading. Any app out there is subject to constant scans and brute force attacks, as you can easily see if you look into your access log. Dealing with a *dedicated* attack going trying to force an app is not going to be deterred by a user/password ban.

Comment: @Tobiq `Isit better to do so?` I assume you mean about running nodejs app behind/inside nginx/apache: yes. You have to consider 1) How will you handle SSL/TLS? 2) Will you need vhosts? An nginx reverse proxy will handle both requirements, if needed. Something like Passenger will also alleviate the need to start-up/sandboxing/monitoring your app, as it will be handled by the web server (via the passenger module). This is really a different question, you should read about how to deploy node in production.

Comment: I guess I'll leave this until the final stages of my App